# javascript array to table layout broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have the following code:

```
function test() {
    var results = "";
    var myArray = [];

    myArray[0] = "Thur May 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)";
    myArray[1] = "Thur May 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)";      
    myArray[2] = "Thur May 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)"; 
    myArray[3] = "Thur May 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)"; 

results = "<table border='1'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i+=2 )

    {    
         results += "<td>Dates</td>";
         results += "<td>Price</td>";
         results += "<td>Available?</td>";
         results += "<tr><td>" + myArray[i+1] + "<tr><td>" + ( myArray[i+1]===undefined ? '' : myArray[i+1] )+ "</tr></td>"; 
    }

    results += "<table><br /> <br />";

    var div = document.getElementById("associatedAssets");
    div.innerHTML = results;    
}
test();
```

I want the following layout:

```
Dates |  Prices |  Available
```

I want my code to populate the date values but I also want the empty rows to populate so the user can manually input the values.

Here is my JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zE2bH/67/

Comment: Check out diz ... http://jsfiddle.net/zE2bH/71/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rkaEA/

Basically the table title needs to be out of the loop. Also; you can use `<td></td>` for empty cells.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using any `<th></th>` tags. These define `header` in your table.

```
results = "<table border='1'>";
results += "<th>";
results +=     "<td>Dates</td>";
results +=     "<td>Price</td>";
results +=     "<td>Available?</td>";
results += "</th>";
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) {    
    results += "<tr>";
    results +=     "<td>" + myArray[i] + "</td>";
    results +=     "<td>PRICE</td>";
    results +=     "<td>" + ( myArray[i]===undefined ? '' : myArray[i] )+ "</td>";
    results += "</tr>"; 
}
results += "<table>";
```

Since the `table` and `header` are static, I'd just leave these inside the HTML and only fill up the `table` with the `rows` accordingly. Note this is only applicible in case there's no condition as to whether or not show any table at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will be helpful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function test() {
        var results = "";
        var myArray = [];
        myArray[0] = "Thur May 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)";
        myArray[1] = "Thur May 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)";
        myArray[2] = "Thur May 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)";
        myArray[3] = "Thur May 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)";
        results = "<table border='1'><tr><td>Dates</td><td>Price</td><td>Available?</td></tr>";
        for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            var date = myArray[i + 1];
            if (date == undefined) {
                date = "";
            }
            results += "<tr><td>" + date
                    + "</td><td>price here</td><td>isAvailable here</td></tr>";
        }
        results += "<table><br /> <br />";
        var div = document.getElementById("associatedAssets");
        div.innerHTML = results;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="associatedAssets"></div>
    <script>
        test();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```